# How to solve "gradle failed resolve"?

Tags: android, build, build.gradle

Can't compile it and can't see in my library.

**Error**

```
gradle failed resolve `com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:+” Compilation fails.
```

**`build.gradle` code**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.backuppc.breathanalyzer"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

**The dependencies**

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:+'

}
```

Comment: If that's all you have in your Gradle file you're probably missing the respositories{} closure that will tell Gradle where to look for dependencies: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management_for_java_projects.html#sec:repositories_java_tutorial

Comment: It's also a good practice not to use the `+` wildcard in the version number but always specify the version number you want to use. The `+` wildcard will tell Gradle to always pick the latest available version of that dependency, but if the authors of that library release a new version with breaking changes in the API, your project will fail to compile all of a sudden

Comment: im using java. and my version of android studio is 1.5.1 i guess sorry im new for this android studio

Comment: heres the error will show > Could not resolve com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.0.+. > Failed to list versions for com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please replace the

```
compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:+'
```

with the latest version

```
compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.0'
```

Please make sure the dependency is of latest version. You can get the latest version here:
https://bintray.com/package/files/arthurhub/maven/Android-Image-Cropper?order=asc&sort=name&basePath=com%2Ftheartofdev%2Fedmodo%2Fandroid-image-cropper&tab=files

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Android Studio Flamingo or above, You can resolve this error by adding

> jcenter()

as the repositories dependency(published using jcenter), in the file

> settings.gradle

Please use the below snippet:

```
repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
        jcenter() 
    }
```